# Referencing element from other component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, checkbox, sharepoint, reference

I've got a checkbox in my `Players.vue`:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="d-inline col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <b>Scholarship Player</b>
   </div>
   <div class="d-inline col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6"> {{ players.Scholarship }} 
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" v-model="players.Scholarship"> </div>
</div>
```

[image: Checkbox]

When the checkbox is checked (true), then another tab should open.

The problem is that the way I reference `players.Scholarship` in my other class `PlayerTabs`, it doesn't seem to work. I get a TypeError:

```
Cannot read property 'Scholarship' of undefined
```

Can someone tell me how I have to reference the `players.Scholarship` (or whether my `if` itself is false)? (I'm new to Vue.js)

```
<div v-if="Scholarship">
    <v-tab title="Scholarship">
      <app-timetables></app-timetables>
    </v-tab>
</div>
<div v-else>
</div>
```

`Scholarship` itself is in an array of `players` in my `TeamInfos.vue` class:

```
playersData: function(data) {
  this.players = [];
  var $this = this;
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $this.players.push({
      ID: data[i].ID,
      PlayerID: data[i].NameId,
      Scholarship: data[i].Scholarship
      // others
    });
  } 
},
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of your setup but my first thoughts are
1. players is an array of player objects
2. players the array does not have a scholarship property
3. Perhaps you should access the individual player in players by using a v-for?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have multiple components. Since you cannot access the data of one component (class) in another component you are not able to reference the `players` from your `Players.vue` in your other component `PlayerTabs.vue` - you have to find a way to pass the data on.

Comment: How can I pass the data on?